# changing pivot table Report Filter with VBA

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have a VBA code that changes the a pivot table Report Filter based on a cell.

It all works fine with inputs that are alphanumeric. When the input is a number, I get an error.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ProjSelect_PivotsUpdate()
    Dim Selected_Proj

    Selected_Proj = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("SelectedProj")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Project").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Project").CurrentPage = _
    Selected_Proj
End Sub
```

Here is the error code:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error.

Answer (score 1):

trimming the value would solve your problem.

```
Sub ProjSelect_PivotsUpdate()
    Dim Selected_Proj

    Selected_Proj = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("SelectedProj")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Project").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Project").CurrentPage =  Trim(Selected_Proj)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Range("SelectedProj") format to string,or just simple add ' before you input a number.

Comment: i also changed the dim line to: Dim Selected_Proj as String and it didn't work. also - adding a character before the number is not feasible because the project name comes from a database.

Comment: I have retest the macro, I found that if the filter do not contain the value you just select, it will get this error, but if the value is on the filter, it will not get error.