# Error changing Pivot Table date range filters via VBA

Tags: vba, date, excel, excel-2010

In Excel 2010, I have created the following "SelectionChange" subroutine in my spreadsheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("i3:i4")) Is Nothing Then
    'Error happens here vvvvvvvv
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add _
      Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=Range("i3").value, Value2:=Range("i4").value
  End If
End Sub
```

When I attempt to execute the code, I get `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`.

I have seen numerous examples on the web of doing this, and the code is cribbed via cut 'n paste. Some examples of this code are [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/560143-date-filter-via-code.html) and [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/560143-date-filter-via-code.html).

I've seen some similar questions asked here at SO, notably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977724/changing-pivot-table-report-filter-with-vba) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240126/change-the-pivot-table-filter-using-vba), however, neither of these seems to have a functional answer, and trying the changes suggested there hasn't helped.

My dates are 'simple' dates, i.e., there is no time component stored in them (when I hit the drop down, I get just a list of dates, they don't have the expansion '+' next to them for multiple times per day). 
I'm entering valid dates, in the same format that the dates are in the data.

I note that IntelliSense doesn't capitalize `.value`, however the error is

I'm pulling the data from one worksheet in the workbook into a pivot table on another worksheet in the same workbook. I plan to have a third worksheet or form where the user will enter the date range to filter the data in the pivot, since pivot filters don't give a simple way of selecting groups of dates. I know I could use the 'group' functionality, however, I won't necessarily be pulling dates for a full month, I need to get it for some random day last month through a random day this month.

/note: this is a standard Pivot Table, not Power Pivot.

Comment: Where the data are stored? Does any PivotTable exists in ActiveSheet?

Comment: The last paragraph details where the data is stored, and yes, there is a pivot table as noted in the very last line.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me.  My fix was to clear the pivot filter and use code like yours, except I converted to value to a date (cause I'm filtering by dates too)...  looks like this

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ptData").PivotFields("Date_Opened").ClearAllFilters

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ptData").PivotFields("Date_Opened").PivotFilters.Add _
    Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=CVDate("2/23/2015"), Value2:=CVDate("4/6/2015")
```